# Regarding different nucleotides on a DNA strand

Tags: nucleotide

I am not a biologist therefore, it might seem as an elementary question. I retrieved rodent sequences from UTR database:

http://utrdb.ba.itb.cnr.it

And I know there are supposed to be four nucleotides namely: A,G,C, and T. However, on this database I get sequences that have 'n' nucleotide in several locations, 'm' and 'k' as well. What does these letters mean? I haven't been able to find anything regarding it. Does it mean these positions in UTR are undefined or they are some 'intermediate' nucleotides if there are any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are [IUPAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Union_of_Pure_and_Applied_Chemistry) codes for so-called ["degenerate" or ambiguous bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleic_acid_notation#IUPAC_notation), alternatives to the usual `A`, `T`, `C`, and `G` nucleotides (for DNA). The `N` code represents any base, while `M` and `K` map to `A` or `C`, and `G` or `T`, respectively.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. That makes much more sense to me now.